# Cannot access the review page

Tags: support, status-completed

I was doing my job reviewing close votes but when I finished my 40 daily review the review page https://stackoverflow.com/review is not loading.

It stuck loading and then display the page https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/review:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

If you need help to debug it let me know.
Anyway I can post all the different pictures :D:

[image]

Comment: Had the same issue about a half an hour ago, when I was about to submit the issue here it started working again, and now it happens again. It's worth saying that it's just `/review` that fails, and just on `SO` (not `MSO`).

Comment: same for me. /review system failed

Comment: And I spent about 10 minutes "reviewing" the different images they use by constantly refreshing. I should get a badge for that (or a life)

Comment: Yeah. sure :) @codeMagic

Comment: I'm having the same problem except instead of a cute cat I have Derpy looking guy pointing at a keyboard.

Comment: Things are falling over a bit right now. We're looking into it.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks. I also experienced a logoff a few times

Comment: @giammin working now for me now

Comment: @TGMCians really slow to load but working!

Comment: It's probably all the robo-reviewers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nick will be investigating further later on, but for the moment the access issues for /review should be resolved.

Comment: I can confirm that it is working, It is slow to load but working, thanks!

Comment: I can get in again but I agree it's fairly slow.

Comment: I'm not sure the slowness is related? I've noticed the review page being sporadically but somewhat frequently quite slow for the past couple weeks, compared to before that.

Comment: it is still extremely slow...